# run commands based on awk find from a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I am trying to run some commands based on strings matched using awk from a file.
I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it.
Is it more apt to use grep for this?

```
#!/bin/bash
file1='ip.txt'
while read line; do 
  if `awk -F: '2 == /puppetclient/'` then 
    echo "Found the IP `awk '{print $1}'` with the text `awk '{print $2}'`"
    echo "Will install puppet agent"
  fi
  if `awk -F: '2 == /puppetmaster/'` then
    echo "Found the IP `awk '{print $1}'` with the text `awk '{print $2}'`"
    echo "Will install puppet server"
  fi
done < $file1
```

**ip.txt**

```
{
52.70.194.83 puppetclient
54.158.170.48 puppetclient
44.198.46.141 puppetclient
54.160.145.116 puppetmaster puppet
}
```

Comment: So many issues. (a) You `-F:` but there is no `:` in the data. (b) By `2` you mean `$2`. (c) `/xx/` is a pattern, so the operator needs to be `~`. (d) What commands do you need to run, and where do you expect to call them. (e) You probably only want to install once, not for every match. (f) awk reads files -- don't use shell read. (g) awk does not see `line` -- it will read stdin.

Comment: Also it is prudent to test before you post. `shellcheck.net` throws six shell errors even before it tries to execute the awk wsections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use awk at all for this as it's providing no benefit and introducing extra complexity and inefficiency. Shells exist to manipulate files and processes and sequence calls to tools and that's exactly what you're doing - writing a script to sequence calls to some commands. You don't need to call an external tool like awk from shell just to compare 2 strings as part of that.

Just do this in shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
file1='ip.txt'
while read -r ip role rest; do
    case $role in
        puppetclient )
            echo "Found the IP $ip with the text $role"
            echo "Will install puppet agent"
            command_to_install_puppet_agent
            ;;
        puppetmaster )
            echo "Found the IP $ip with the text $role"
            echo "Will install puppet server"
            command_to_install_puppet_server
            ;;
    esac
done < "$file1"
```

Comment: Thank you, i was looking for such simple solution but could not get my head around the logic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all sure why you want to loop around the file instead of just using `awk` directly

```
awk '
    /puppetclient/ {
        printf "Found the IP %s with the text %s\n", $1, $2
        printf "Will install puppet agent\n"
        system ("echo agent magic")    # Execute this command
    }
    /puppetmaster/ {
        printf "Found the IP %s with the text %s\n", $1, $2
        printf "Will install puppet server\n"
        system ("echo server magic")    # Execute this command
    }
' ip.txt
```

Comment: A shell is a tool to manipulate (create/destroy). files and processes and sequence calls to tools. Awk is a tool to manipulate text. You're using awk to do what a shell should do and so you're ending up with a call stack like `shell { awk { system { shell { echo } } } }` with awk spawning a new subshell once per input line to call echo. There's just no reason to involve awk as a middleman instead of just doing `shell { echo }`.